# send MMS in a specific format

Tags: android

i want to send Text Message with and Icon in it via Message in android phone

and in a ***following format***

[image]

1. Using MMS is it possible to achieve it ?
2. Is it necessary  for
   another user to have MMS enable in order to receive the MMS ?
3. Is
   there way to know whether other user's having MMS Enabled in his
   phone ?

Answer (score 2):

> Using MMS is it possible to achieve it ?

You can attach the image, but it is upto the client to position it in any place (or display it at all really)

> Is it necessary for another user to have MMS enable in order to receive the MMS ?

The other device should have an SMS client that support MMS. Some devices may refuse to receive the message if the user has disabled it, but most won't.

> Is there way to know whether other user's having MMS Enabled in his phone ?

No.

Comment: it is upto the client means , cant we set the position programactically and even without using MMS in built intent of android?

Comment: @Hunt You can display it wherever you want on the User's device if you are writing the MMS app, but if the person the user sent it to doesn't use your app, there is no guarantee where it will be displayed.